# Hive table location in S3 w/o slashes

Tags: amazon-s3, hive, aws-glue

I've got S3 access logs getting dumped to a bucket in what's apparently a Hive (Glue Data Catalog) unfriendly structure.  Basically, they're given a prefix ending in a slash, then each file name begins with a date string, but they're not separated into 'sub-directories' below that (I know S3 doesn't do directories, but lots of things like to pretend it does - e.g. Hive & the S3 web console). The files end up looking like this:

```
s3://logs-bucket/some-prefix/2020-01-01-00-18-09-0D4ABDAC9C0DA971
s3://logs-bucket/some-prefix/2020-02-02-00-18-32-F4326DB4C0F61E87
s3://logs-bucket/some-prefix/2020-02-02-00-27-32-75841FC1705062CA
...
```

and there's millions of them like this.

I'm trying to figure out how to define either a Hive table or partition scheme that separates those files based on date. Without that I have to scan the entire prefix, even if I know the data I'm looking for is in files with names beginning with a given date.

I've tried defining a table named 's3_logs_2020-02' at location `'s3://logs-bucket/some-prefix/2020-02'`. I also tried a partitioned table rooted at the prefix, and with that same location for the '2020-02' partition. In both cases the data is not found because Hive (Glue?) appears to implicitly add a '/' at the end of the location string.

So the question is, is there any way to tell Hive not to implicitly add that trailing slash to S3 locations?

EDIT:
An alternative I've looked at is to add a where-clause to my queries using the "$path" pseudo-column.  This works to reduce the actual returned results, but it's not clear to me whether it reduces the actual S3 paths scanned.  Does anyone know if it does?

Comment: technically s3 has no folders. But HDFS has.  Hive partition is a folder in Hadoop-compatible fylesystem.  And for compatibility reasons many tools pretend s3 has folders but actually those folders are prefixes. And there are many optimizations done for listing prefixes. No way to tell Hive to use some prefix as a folder. You can implement Lambda executing on S3 event and moving files to daily folders, read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47118448/2700344

Comment: ya ok - I suspected this was the case, but just wanted to ask the broader community in case I was missing something.  We'll look at restructuring the layout of the log files.  Thx :)